# Jquery validation on login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Hello guys I'm doing a login form with jquery validation which checks if the user id and password are valid.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){  

    $("#loginForm").validate({
        rules: {
         username: "required",
         password: {
           required: true
         }
        },
        messages: {
         username: "This field is required",
         password: {
           required: "This field is required"
         }
        }
    });

    $("#loginForm").submit(function(){  

    $("#report").removeClass().addClass('loader').html('<img src="img/login/spinner.gif">').fadeIn(1000);  
    $.post("checklogin.php",{ username:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val()},function(data){  
        if(data=='yes'){  
        $("#report").fadeTo(200,1,function(){       
        $(this).html('<img src="img/login/spinner.gif">').addClass('log').fadeTo(900,1,function(){          
                document.location='processed.php';  
             });       
         });  
        }
        else {  
        $("#report").fadeTo(200,1,function(){        
        $(this).html('<img src="img/login/icon_error.gif"> Username or password error.').addClass('error').fadeTo(900,1);  
            });    
        }  
        });  
        return false;   
    });  
    $("#password").blur(function(){  
    $("#login_form").trigger('submit');  
        });  
    }); 

</script>
```

What I want to happen is, if fields have empty values then it should validate and display fields are required. But my form displays the error message and goes to check as if the fields have values. Why is that happening? Any ideas to resolve this issue? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** index.html

```
  <form class="form-signin" action="checklogin.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
    <img alt="" src="img/irasa_logoa.png" title="IRASA"> 
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Log In</h2>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="User ID" name="username" id="username" class="required">
    <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" class="required">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-custom" type="submit">Log in</button>
    <div id="report"></div>
  </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#loginForm").validate({
        rules: {
         username: "required",
         password: "required"

        },
        messages: {
         username: "This field is required",
         password: "This field is required"
        },
            submitHandler: function(form) {

             $("#report").removeClass().addClass('loader').html('<img src="img/login/spinner.gif">').fadeIn(1000);  
            $.post("checklogin.php",{ username:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val()},function(data){  
                if(data=='yes'){  
                    $("#report").fadeTo(200,1,function(){       
                        $(this).html('<img src="img/login/spinner.gif">').addClass('log').fadeTo(900,1,function(){          
                            document.location='processed.php';  
                        });       
                    });  
                } else {  
                    $("#report").fadeTo(200,1,function(){        
                        $(this).html('<img src="img/login/icon_error.gif"> Username or password error.').addClass('error').fadeTo(900,1);  
                    });    
                }  
            });  
            return false;   
        })

 }); 
 $("#password").blur(function(){  
     $("#login_form").trigger('submit');   
 });

      }
    });
```

Comment: Hello I tried this, but I'm not getting the ajax one, instead I was redirected to checklogin.php and got stuck there

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery validate then you should not also bind to the submit event for the form yourself.  Put that code in a submitHandler instead.  See http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler

**Edit to add example.**
Note that I have not checked that your function (which you had as a submit event) is right - just copied it.  I have also removed the rules since as @Sambhav Sharma said, you should simply add a "required" class to the fields and it is automatically required).  I also assume the submit on blur should be triggered always, not after the validation submit.  I have not tested any of this :)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  

     $("#loginForm").validate({
            messages: {
             username: "This field is required",
             password: {
               required: "This field is required"
             }
            },
            submitHandler: function(){  
                $("#report").removeClass().addClass('loader').html('<img src="img/login/spinner.gif">').fadeIn(1000);  
                $.post("checklogin.php",{ username:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val()},function(data){  
                    if(data=='yes'){  
                        $("#report").fadeTo(200,1,function(){       
                            $(this).html('<img src="img/login/spinner.gif">').addClass('log').fadeTo(900,1,function(){          
                                document.location='processed.php';  
                            });       
                        });  
                    } else {  
                        $("#report").fadeTo(200,1,function(){        
                            $(this).html('<img src="img/login/icon_error.gif"> Username or password error.').addClass('error').fadeTo(900,1);  
                        });    
                    }  
                });  
                return false;   
            })

     }); 
     $("#password").blur(function(){  
         $("#login_form").trigger('submit');   
     }); 
 });
```

Comment: I tried this but I was redirected to checklogin.php and got stuck there

Comment: If no errors then you need to start setting breakpoints in the javascript and steping through and see what is happening.  Maybe remove all the messages stuff and check the submit handler works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is as simple as adding a "required" class in your input type. just add class="required". 
This will work as you're using jquery.validate.min.js.

Refer: http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=194

Comment: Yes I already have that, but it is still not doing my intention.

Comment: did you try and do an inspect element and checked in console if there was a js error prevailing?

Comment: I don't have any errors in the console, it just redirects to checklogin.php when the ajax should be called